# Exportar/Importar IIFE (función autoejecutable) en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, clausuras, iife

Estoy intentando exportar la siguiente función pero cuando hago el renderizado no veo nada ni tampoco arroja error. Debe devolver un objeto **JSON**:

```
export const random = (resp) => { return resp} 

((min,max) => {
        let arr = [];
        let coincidencia = {}
        for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){                                                              let valor_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min)
                arr.push(valor_random)
        }
        arr.forEach(function(numero){
                coincidencia[numero] = (coincidencia[numero] || 0) + 1;
        });
        random(coincidencia) 
}) (1,20) ;
```

En cambio si hago así, si funciona. Pero justamente no es lo que quiero, simplemente quiero que el código quede encapsulado empleando **IIFE**:

```
export const random = (min,max) => {
        let arr = [];
        let coincidencia = {}
        for(let i=0; i<10000; i++){                                                              let valor_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min)
                arr.push(valor_random)
        }
        arr.forEach(function(numero){
                coincidencia[numero] = (coincidencia[numero] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return coincidencia
}
```

Ambos son llamados de la siguiente manera en mi archivo app.js:

```
router.get('/random', (req,res) => {
        res.json(random()); // para llamar al código que quiero que funcione. 
});
```

Sino tengo que hacer lo mismo, pero pasándole los parámetros ahí mismo.

Gracias, espero haber sido claro.

Comment: Se utiliza ```module.exports```

Comment: Christian, estoy trabajando con ES Modules

Comment: En la segunda forma exportar la función pero en la primera no lo haces así, deberías de ponerle nombre a esa función o almacenarla en una variable y luego exportarla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisa los ejemplos sobre [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE#ejemplos), en el segundo dice que:

> Asignar el IIFE a una variable almacena el valor de retorno, no la definición de la función.

Y por lo que entiendo, tú lo que quieres es devolver el resultado de la ejecución de tu IIFE (que por lo que pude ver es un objeto con 20 propiedades -del 1 al 20- con un valor numérico que indica la ocurrencia de cada uno de ellos dentro de los 1000 números generados aleatoriamente) y no la función como tal.

Entonces partiendo de estos dos puntos podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
// iife.js

export const random = ((min, max) => {
  let arr = [];
  let coincidencia = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let valor_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    arr.push(valor_random)
  }
  arr.forEach(function (numero) {
    coincidencia[numero] = (coincidencia[numero] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return coincidencia
})(1, 20);
```

```javascript
// importIife.js

import { random } from "./iife.mjs";

console.log(random);
```

Lo que da como resultado:

```
{
  '1': 461,
  ...
  '20': 469
}
```

Básicamente asignar el resultado de tu IIFE a la propiedad `random` del módulo, y como es una función ejecutada inmediatamente, almacenarás el resultado y no la definición, luego puedes importar ese resultado en otro módulo y ver su valor. Dado que ya se ha *auto ejecutado*, no es necesario importar y llamar a la función, simplemente puedes hacer uso directamente como si fuera una "variable" más -a pesar de ser una constante, cada vez que ejecutes nuevamente el archivo de donde importas `random` (*importIife.js* en este caso), este cambiará de valor y permanecerá constante durante ese tiempo de ejecución-.

### Extra:

Si haces uso de [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) y [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) -y las arrow functions- puedes reducir el código (realmente solo reduce dos líneas -sin contar las líneas de comentarios- pero es más entendible, aunque si quisieras podrías hacer el `.reduce()` directamente de `Array.from()` sin pasar por la variable `array`) de tu IIFE a lo siguiente:

```javascript
// iife.js

const randomNumber = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // Puede estar fuera o dentro de random, es indiferente ya que no se exporta.

export const random = ((min, max, length = 10000) => {
  const array = Array.from({ length }, () => randomNumber(min, max)); // Crear un array desde un iterable y una mapFn sin pasar por un array intermedio. Ver documentación.

  // Reducir el array a un objeto con las ocurrencias de cada número generado.
  return array.reduce((coincidencia, numero) => {
    coincidencia[numero] = (coincidencia[numero] || 0) + 1;
    return coincidencia;
  }, {});
})(1, 20); // Puedes cambiar la longitud o dejar que se haga con el default: 10000.
```

Comment: Gracias Ricardo por la explicación y por señalar también Array.from y reduce para simplificar un poco más el código. Ya pude solucionarlo